# create a new object or re-use it

Tags: java, sqlite, class, oop, jdbc

i have to parse huge data from xml files from a loop and insert values into sqlite database. i am thinking of instead of calling :

```
PreparedStatement ps = conn.prepareStatement("insert into "+TABLE_NAME+" ("+NAME_COL+", "+AGE_COL+", "+ADDRESS_COL+", "+GENDER_COL+") values (?, ?, ?, ?)");
```

each iteration in the loop, to add the values into list and pass it to the method that does record insertion.

my question is, should i create a "new" list after every record insertion or remove all elements in the list and reuse it. which suits huge data manipulation and yields good performance

Comment: I would reuse the object after the database id of the record was assigned.

Comment: @StefanBeike you mean i should remove the elements fro the list after the record insertion and reuse the list , right?

Answer (score 0):

here is my suggestion.

1) Create a class as below along with paramterized constructor with getters & setters.

```
class TABLE_NAME{
     datatype NAME_COL;
    datatype AGE_COL
    datatype ADDRESS_COL
    datatype GENDER_COL
    }
```

2) make Simple statements that executes once.

```
    TABLE_NAME tablename;
String sql = "INSERT INTO" +TABLE_NAME+"values (?, ?, ?, ?)";
PreparedStatement ps = conn.prepareStatement(sql);
```

3) code as below

```
    Loop through the XML{
//create a object tablename with values in the XML
tablename = new tablename(value1,values2,value3,value4);
ps.setString(1,tablename.getParameter1());
ps.setString(2,tablename.getParameter2());
ps.setString(3,tablename.getParameter3());
ps.setString(4,tablename.getParameter4());
ps.execute()
}
//end of loop
```

This is as per me, you may no need to create the object also, and still go ahead by setting values directly in the setString function.

Comment: u mean , and insert an object of that class into a list and then pass the list to the method that does the records insertion?

Comment: This will lead to iterating twice. once for creating the list of objects and the other for inserting the list containing objects.

Answer (score 0):

You should use one single `insert`-command because its a part of the [ACID-Pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ACID).

You can build the multi-insert-sql like this:

```
INSERT INTO (...) VALUES (1,2,3),(1,2,4),(1,2,5),...
```

EDIT:

You should better tune the parsing instead of the insert.

```
ExecutorService es = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(8);
```

May guide you to a parallel processing tune in environments using highperformance the CPU who having 8 threads.

Comment: ok, but i think this means the insert statement will be called several times, because it will be called from the loop, which contradicts with what u suggested in ur post..kindly please advice

Comment: is the way u suggestd is faster, because i have to parse a file the contains < 500 million lines, and insert some parsed data into DB

Comment: @rmaik All-in-one-sql is faster, but you better tune the parsing.